# Parsing DBUS response type as Array of Dictionary or Map using C++

Tags: c++, linux, glib, dbus, glibmm

I am working on Linux DBUS APIs using C++ code, trying to run a dbus method and parse response message typeof (a{sv}) But having few problems. I am using glib and glibmm libraries.

here is my code:

```
    const auto call_result = proxy -> call_sync("GetConfiguration",
    tuple, 1000);

std::cout << "Contents of call_result: " << call_result.print() <<
    std::endl;
std::cout << "call_result type: " <<
    call_result.get_type_string() << std::endl;

Glib::Variant < std::vector < std::map < Glib::ustring, Glib::VariantBase >>> testConfigVect;

call_result.get_child(testConfigVect, 0);
std::cout << "testConfigVect type: " <<
    testConfigVect.get_type_string() << std::endl;

std::size_t numChildren = testConfigVect.get_n_children();
std::cout << "numChildren: " << numChildren << std::endl;

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {

    auto mapa = testConfigVect.get_child(i);
    const char * typeName = typeid(mapa).name();
    std::cout << "Type of mapa: " << typeName << std::endl;

    if (mapa.empty()) {
        std::cout << "Map is empty." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Map is not empty." << std::endl;
    }

    for (const auto & pair: mapa) {
        const Glib::ustring & key = pair.first;
        const Glib::VariantBase & value = pair.second;

        std::cout << "Key: " << key << ", Value: " << value.print() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I found an empty map But I can see a valid dbus response is a{sv} format with map information.
Wonder why I am not able to read map here !
here is the output of my code:

```
Contents of call_result: ({'SecureBoot': <'False'>},) 
call_result type: (a{sv}) 
testConfigVect type: a{sv} 
numChildren: 1 
Type of mapa:
St3mapIN4Glib7ustringENS0_11VariantBaseESt4lessIS1_ESaISt4pairIKS1_S2_EEE
Map is empty.
```

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion here seems to be in `a{sv}`: this is not an array of dictionary, it's just a dictionary. You can read the format string as *"array of key-value pairs"*, see [GVariant format strings](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/gvariant-format-strings.html) for more details.

So if you treat testConfigVect as a map, that will likely start working.

Comment: Thanks @Jussi Kukkonen for the answer, But my call_result is of type
Glib::VariantContainerBase , so I am n ot sure we can use g_variant*  methods. can you suggest a way to parse data using same types ?

Comment: I only linked to the format strings docs because you print format strings in your code and those format strings don't seem to match the code you have. 

You declare the call return value as `Glib::Variant < std::vector < std::map < Glib::ustring, Glib::VariantBase >>>`: a vector of maps. As I mentioned `a{sv}` is not a vector of maps, it's a map. Have your tried `Glib::Variant < std::map < Glib::ustring, Glib::VariantBase >>` (and modifying the printing code to match)?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked ! Thanks @Jussi Kukkonen

```
Glib::Variant < std::map < Glib::ustring, Glib::VariantBase >> dictVariant;

call_result.get_child(dictVariant, 0);
std::cout << "dictVariant type: " <<
  dictVariant.get_type_string() << std::endl;


std::map < Glib::ustring, Glib::VariantBase > mapData = dictVariant.get();


for (const auto & pair: mapData) {
  const Glib::ustring & key = pair.first;
  const Glib::VariantBase & value = pair.second;

  std::cout << "Key: " << key << std::endl;
}
```